# What are other text editors using in place of Sublime's "go to anything"

Tags: vim, emacs, notepad++, text-editors, sublime-text-2

Sublime's "go to anything" is a functionality that allows you to fastly go to any file or symbol inside a file by just typing a few keystrokes.

Comment: I don't think this question deserved to be closed. However, this feature doesn't "go to any file", it's limited to the files currently opened in ST2 or belonging to the same project. If we limit ourselves to solutions also using fuzzy matching, TextMate (AFAIK, the original implementation of this idea) uses "Go to File…" bound to `Cmd+T`, Vim has a number of plugins for that (Cmd-T, CtrlP, FuzzyFinder, LustyExplorer, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

[Control+f] = {find} is a universal Windows command in any windows App, that many 3rd party apps use.. sometimes different...
Of course ctrl+p for goto anything in sublime [and in OSX command+p] and ctrl+f in Win or command+f in OSX = find is similar to GOTO ANYTHING as in most other editors.

Sublime is unique in it's multi symbolic script editing and formatting. and GOTO ANYTHING does not require contiguous text as FIND does. so it is very editor specific.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Wincent Colaiuta's popular Command T plugin.

On Vim.org - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025

On Github - https://github.com/wincent/Command-T

Answer (score 0):

Emacs has [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki) which can probably do this (I haven't checked, but it has lots of plugins) and much more.